# ‎If ‎$‎\lim‎ f(x) = L‎$ as ‎$‎x‎\rightarrow ‎+‎\infty‎$‎, then $‎\lim‎ f(c x) = L‎$ as $‎x‎\rightarrow ‎+‎\infty‎$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

‎Let ‎‎$‎f‎$ ‎be a‎ ‎real-variable ‎function ‎such ‎that ‎‎$‎‎‎‎‎\lim‎‎ f(x) = L‎$ as ‎$‎x‎‎\rightarrow ‎+‎\infty‎$ where $‎L\in‎\mathbb{R}‎$‎. ‎Also, let‎ $‎c‎>0‎$ be a constant. My question is:‎
‎

Is $‎‎‎‎\lim‎ f(c x) = L‎$ as $‎x‎‎\rightarrow ‎+‎\infty‎‎$?‎
‎

My attempt:‎
‎
Define ‎$‎c x = t‎$‎. Since ‎‎$‎x‎‎\rightarrow ‎+‎\infty‎$ ‎and‎ $‎c‎>0‎$ then $‎t‎‎\rightarrow ‎+‎\infty‎$, so ‎ ‎‎$‎‎‎‎‎\lim‎‎ f(t) = L‎$ as ‎$‎x‎‎\rightarrow ‎+‎\infty‎$. Is this it correct?

Comment: I can answer your question in one line. Please add your own work to the question, so that it may be reopened and I shall do so.

Comment: Rhys Hughes. Hi. I suppose that $c x = t$. ‎Since $‎x‎‎\rightarrow ‎+‎\infty‎$ ‎and‎ $‎c‎>0‎$, ‏‎thus ‎‎$‎t‎‎\rightarrow ‎+‎\infty‎$‎, so $‎‎‎‎\lim‎ f(t) = L‎$.

Comment: But I do not know right.

Comment: That's pretty much there, but you should add it to your question via an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\forall c\in\Bbb R^+; x\to \infty \iff cx\to\infty$$

That's all you need.